# Passing a JavaScript variable to fill innerHTML

Tags: javascript, forms, ejs

I'm trying to pass a simple variable from a form input to populate a span with the .innerHTML syntax. My code (with search.ejs) is as follows:

```
<script>function readSearchValue() {
      var passedSearchValue = document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();
      document.getElementById('mySearch').innerHTML = passedSearchValue;
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Search form -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <form class="form-inline" id="searchForm">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="searchValue">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit" onclick="readSearchValue()"></button>
    </form>
  </nav>

<p>You have searched for:
    <span id="mySearch"></span>
  </p>
```

I also have a search.js file which doesn't do much ATM:

```
res.render('search', {
        title: 'Search results',
```

I get an undefined error with the code above. Thanks in advance for any help!

Kelly.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use ejs expression if you are sending value from the server. if you want to work on the local side then you can see the below code.

```js
function readSearchValue() {
      document.getElementById('mySearch').innerHTML = document.getElementById('searchValue').value;
      document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();
    }
```

```html
<!-- Search form -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <form class="form-inline" id="searchForm" method="POST">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" id="searchValue">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="button" onclick="readSearchValue();">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </nav>

<p>You have searched for:
    <span id="mySearch"></span>
  </p>
```

For now, you cannot see value permanent because the form is submitting so the page is reloading.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My eventual aim is to pass the URL to a database query actually (the query is within my routes folder). Do you have any points for how I can process this variable server side?

Comment: @KellyB Now you can get data in the request. You can check on the server using req.body.search

Answer (score 0):

Your code is near complete. The only thing you need to change is the 2nd line of "readSearchValue" function. Set innerHTML of "mySearch" box to the value of "searchValue" input field. The code - `document.getElementById("mySearch").innerHTML = document.getElementById("searchValue").value`